# DefaultDict Switching Key-Pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I am using DefaultDict to create a dictionary and for some reason, it seems to be switching the key and pair and I am not sure why.

```
recurring_suppliers[supplier_name] = (
                    float(transaction_amount))
                print(supplier_name)
                print(transaction_amount)
                print(recurring_suppliers)
```

The output is the following:

```
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {})
תמרי-וקסר אחזקות בע"מ
2340.0
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'תמרי-וקסר אחזקות בע"מ': 2340.0})
```

Here is the DefaultDict declaration as well:

```
recurring_suppliers = defaultdict(str)
```

Any idea why the formatting is printed this way? I've never experienced this after using DefaultDict often. I am also confused by the single quotes at the start of the number and after the colon. Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm certain that this is because your supplier is in Hebrew. I can replicate this bug using Hebrew, but when I use English I don't have this bug.

Comment: What's happening is that on a low-level, no keys and values are being switched. The interpreter is trying to be nice to your and print the key-value from right to left (because it's Hebrew). So the first ' comes because it's the beginning of the print statement, but then the last one comes in the right place. A check of `recurring_suppliers.keys()` shows that the data is being stored as expected.

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense, thank you!